# Fetch Amazon Customer Review Contents by Link. How?

Tags: php, simple-html-dom, review, amazon-product-api

Currently, my way of fetching the Amazon Customer Review by Review Link is by using

[PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjH6o7Zj-DRAhWMn5QKHcZhBKYQFggYMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsimplehtmldom.sourceforge.net%2F&usg=AFQjCNEj25gYEBl4te-VvReRxFLr8EHXMA&sig2=z8ER7AZrOEdiKYXPwAorkA&bvm=bv.145063293,d.dGo).

By providing the review Link, I can fetch out the Review Contents like
Title, Ratings Comments, Description, Images, Videos, Author, etc.

This is all possible if I know the [css selector](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiQzeaRkODRAhXJmJQKHTPrAr8QFggaMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcssref%2Fcss_selectors.asp&usg=AFQjCNHllGwj8IF107DgWz0KANxnLB0kbg&sig2=Q9IjtGEkEW_eejO00VT-8A&bvm=bv.145063293,d.dGo) for each contents.

To show you a sample how I do it:

```
$url = 'REVIEW_URL_HERE';
$html = file_get_html($url,false); //see PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser
$testSelector='#SAMPLE-SELECTOR';
$content = $html->find($testSelector, 0)->plaintext;
//echo $content; //error-> seems selector is not present.
echo $html; // i expect the review link page will be loaded. but the loaded page is different
```

The output was unexpected. since I `echo $html`, I am expecting the Review Page. but a different page was shown:

[image: Screen Snippet]

It seems the method I am using to fetch the Review Contents is not possible anymore. any Ideas for a new method? 
I found AWS regarding fetching Reviews... but AFAIK it doesn't return review contents.. it only returns Review Links..

Answer (score 0):

Sure is but you gotta be an Amazon Developer and use their API. Check out the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CustomerandSellerReviews.html#GettingCustomerReviews).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Eric, as i have mentioned, it will only return iframe src link. and due to cross-domain issues.. i cannot fetch the contents in the iframe... unless you know how?

Comment: You can read the content of an iframe in PHP with file_get_contents or you could even read it in CURL.

Comment: hmmmm okay.. ill check this out and got back to you once got result. :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are seeing this message, because you might have repeatedly calling amazon apis. Amazon is blocking ip address in this case. Change you internet provider, it should start working.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to use php and PhantomJs plus simple Javascript.
And do not forget: use proxies

Some like this:

```
 <?php
 $html = exec("phantomjs --proxy=127.0.0.1:80 --proxy-auth=root:master 
  test.js http://httpbin.org/ip");
 ?>
```

test.js

```
var args = require('system').args;
var webPage = require('webpage');
var address = args[1];
var page = webPage.create();
var fs = require('fs');
var pageResponses = {};

page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false;
phantom.cookiesEnabled = false;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.resourceTimeout = 20000;
page.customHeaders = { // use correct header
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.5",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
};
page.viewportSize = { width: 1024, height: 768 };

try {
    page.open(address, function (status) {
       console.log(page.content);
       window.setTimeout(function () {
          phantom.exit();
      }, Math.random()*500 + 1500);
   });
} catch(e) {
    phantom.exit(1);
}
```